# How do you say "some people" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

Like, if I wanted to say "Some people think　I look like...." how would I say that?

Would it be: some 人觉得我长得像．．．．？

Answer (score 11, accepted):

有人 is someone, some people, anyone.

> 有人觉得我长得像

Answer (score 10):

some people can be translated as 有人，某些人，有些人，有部分人

Comment: There are nuances between 有人 and other phrases - other phrase s have a little bit derogatory sense while 有人 does not.

Answer (score 4):

Some people think I look like

> 有人认为我长的像

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, a simple question, it will be

> 有人觉得我长得像...

but as @charlese said `other phrase s have a little bit derogatory sense`, so be careful when you are saying

> 某些人觉得我长得像
>
> 有一部分人觉得我长得像
>
> 有些人觉得我长得像

How does those phrases have derogatory means? Well, my guess is because China used to criticize someone without mention his name, like

> 有些同志以为...
>
> 有些人已近向糖衣炮弹投降了!
>
> 目前党内有一小部分人...

Answer (score 2):

有人 and 有些人 are the most used ones.

In your sentence, it should be 有（些）人觉得我长得像．．．．？

Answer (score 1):

Should be translated to 有人 or 有的人

Difference:
有人 is declarative sentence, no emotion, just someone.
有的人 has a kind of emotion, usually their attitude will be attached, a kind of that one.

Statement of fact:
有人觉得饭菜不好吃，勉强吃一点，剩下的就都倒掉了。

Own comment and judgment:
有的人！觉得饭菜稍微不合自己的胃口，就都倒掉！浪费可耻，这是什么行为？！现在还有几亿人忍受饥饿的煎熬，他们却这样不知珍惜和羞耻。谁知盘中餐，粒粒皆辛苦啊！

And:
有的人活着
他已经死了
有的人死了
他还活着
……